Can normalizing flows approximate bounded distributions in deep learning?
I’m exploring the use of normalizing flows in deep learning for generative modeling and I have a specific requirement: my target distributions are bounded (for example, between 0 and 1). I understand that normalizing flows transform a simple distribution (like a standard normal distribution) into a more complex one through a series of invertible and differentiable transformations.
However, I’m unsure about how to ensure that the resulting distributions are bounded. What strategies can be employed to make normalizing flows approximate bounded distributions effectively? Say, if the true target distribution behaves like a Beta distribution.
